# Possible to upload a file to multiple libraries at once? [SharePoint 2013]

Tags: document, library, file, share

I have multiple departments who have their own subsite. Each department has their own Document Library. Is it possible that when a user uploads a file, that the user sends the file to multiple department Document libraries at once?

My goal is that i want a file shared to another existing document library.

Thanks

Comment: Though this is doable, it creates a nightmare to keep such documents in synch. Are these documents free and independent clones that don't require syncing after upload?

Comment: No, there will be new versions of documents. I guess old fasion network drive sharing will work easier?

Comment: Well in such a case, you could always use workflow to copy the uploaded document to the other libraries.

Comment: Good tip, i will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a workflow, i partially reached my goal using a content query web part. I've made a document library for department X with a column named departments. If the uploader chooses department Y from a drop down menu, the file will be placed into the content query library located on the site of department Y. Only the files with the correct department will be shown because of a filter. The steps I've used are in this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kECKzd04kg